# Is there a neater way to refactor code that is run for multiple event listeners?

Tags: javascript

Here is a trivial example of some code that I want to execute when either the load or resize event fires.

```
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    winHeight = window.innerHeight;
    div.style.width = winWidth + "px";
    div.style.height = winHeight + "px";
  });

  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    winHeight = window.innerHeight;
    div.style.width = winWidth + "px";
    div.style.height = winHeight + "px";
  });
```

I could put the repeated code in a function and do

```
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    setDivSize();
  });

  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    setDivSize();
  });

  let setDivSize = function() {
    winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    winHeight = window.innerHeight;
    div.style.width = winWidth + "px";
    div.style.height = winHeight + "px";
  }
```

This is probably good enough for code this small, but I was wondering if there is something better you can do to execute the same code for multiple event listeners? Say I want to execute the same code on keypress, resize, click, and load... is this the best I can do?

Comment: If you define function before. You do not need to pass anon function. You can simply do 
`window.addEventListener('load', setDivSize);` and `window.addEventListener('resize', setDivSize);`

Answer (score 2):

You could make it shorter by iterating over an array of event names:

```
for (const eventName of ['load', 'resize']) {
  window.addEventListener(eventName, () => {
    winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    winHeight = window.innerHeight;
    div.style.width = winWidth + "px";
    div.style.height = winHeight + "px";
  });
}
```

If you wanted, you could define the function outside beforehand, but it almost certainly won't make any difference:

```
const handleEvent = () => {
  winWidth = window.innerWidth;
  winHeight = window.innerHeight;
  div.style.width = winWidth + "px";
  div.style.height = winHeight + "px";
};
for (const eventName of ['load', 'resize']) {
  window.addEventListener(eventName, handleEvent);
}
```

Comment: That creates multiple functions, one for each event, rather than multiple references to the one function as in the OP's second example.